How to Quantize the Return Type of a Function in an LLVM Pass?
I'm developing an LLVM pass to quantize a function by changing its return type from float to int32. Specifically, I have a function called mulfix with the following definition:
 define dso_local float @mulfix(i32 %0, i32 %1)
I want to change it to:
 define dso_local i32 @mulfix(i32 %0, i32 %1)
I encountered issues with directly erasing the old function. When I use eraseFromParent, it sometimes causes segmentation faults or other bugs. Is there a more robust way to handle this transition without directly erasing the old function?
Any help or pointers would be greatly appreciated. Thank you

It probably segfaulted for functions where function->getNumUses() returned nonzero. Deleting functions is a normal thing to d, dangling links are the only issue that I know of.

There isn't enough detail here. eraseFromParent works and does what it says, so why does it crash? What you're doing sounds like a case for replaceAllUsesWith + eraseFromParent. Is that what you're doing? How do you handle all the call instructions that no longer have float type but i32 type? You need to RAUW+erase them all too. Did you do that first? Is your function used in any ConstantExpr's?
